# get_term_children returns unknown int though term has no child

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I am running get_term_children to check if a term has children.  On a term which does not have have children wp returns an array containing a single int : 12 though that does not relate to any term.  I did recently delete a child term though.

```
 $hasChildren = get_term_children( $categories[$i]->term_id, 'my_tax' );
 var_dump($hasChildren);
```

returns

```
array (size=1)
0 => int 12
```

Comment: "doesn't not"? Is that double negative on purpose? I can't reproduce this. The function works as expected when I test it.

Comment: @s_ha_dum edited.

Comment: I can't duplicate this. I even deleted a child category. The function returns an empty array.

Comment: you need to delete an option named `my_tax_children` from options table. try running `delete_option('my_tax_children')` once on your themes `functions.php` file, and then remove it.

Comment: @Shazzad nope no joy

Comment: What is the name of the option you have deleted ? and what is your Custom Tax name ?

Comment: I've not deleted an option name, I deleted a term.

Comment: Ok, try deleting deleting an option, named 'YOUR_CUSTOM_TAXONOMY_children' using delete_option function

Comment: @Shazzad Wordked, can you post an answer explaining why? Thanks

Comment: @Shazzad this should be the answer to this question. Please post so it can be upvoted and accepted

Answer (score 0):

WordPress saves all taxonomy children term ids in an option for caching purpose. The option is named `"$taxonomy_children"`. This option is created when you use the function `get_term_children`, but does not get updated that way. It's only updated upon creating/updating parent or child term of that taxonomy using WP Admin UI.

Rather than using WP Admin UI, if you deleted a term some other way, the option exists and therefore display wrong children information upon using `get_term_children` function. To solve this problem, you should manually delete the option named **"$taxonomy_children"** using the `delete_option` function or directly from your **phpMyAdmin**

Comment: This appears to have worked, but I did not need to manually delete that option value after deleting a category. I think there has to be something else at work here.

Comment: i meant if deletion was done using `phpMyAdmin` or other way rather than using `wp_delete_term` function.

Comment: I think something like that has to be the case. Your solution apparently works. I am just trying to clarify the circumstances so that people finding this later are not confused.